# What is the best way to calculate customer balance?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

### I need help with the below

**Background**

There are two tables, **Withdrawal** and **Deposit**. Each store `customerID`, `amount` and `date`.

> What is the best way to  calculate customer balance ?

### Option 1.

---

Add another table called **customer_balance** with fields `customerID`,`balance` and `update balance` field on every transaction.

*sql triggers can be used*

### Option 2.

---

```
balance = sum of customer Deposits - sum of withdrawals
```

*sql stored procedure or view can be used*

> I also want to know how banking and inventory management systems
>   calculate balances

Comment: The best solution could be related to which RDBMS technology you are using.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Tell us your [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Database_management_systems) as well since answers may be different for each DBMS. Help us help you!

Comment: I use MS SQL Server with VB.NET.
I want to know the best way to get  customer balance

Comment: Best in regard of which criteria?

Comment: @user1519220 Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide your table structure and a output format of data requiring.

Comment: "I also want to know how banking and inventory management systems calculate balances".  This makes the question too broad.

Comment: This is a how I calculate student balance

--tables

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BillStudent](
 [STUDENTID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [AMOUNT] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
 [EntryDate] [datetime] NULL,
 [EntryTime] [time](0) NULL,
 [Comment] [varchar](200) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FeePayment](
 [STUDENTID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [ReceiptNo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [AMOUNT] [numeric](10, 2) NOT NULL,
 [EntryDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [EntryTime] [time](0) NULL,
 [Comment] [varchar](200) NULL)

Comment: --student balance using view

SELECT a.STUDENTID, CAST(a.mysum - ISNULL(b.mysum, 0) AS numeric(10, 2)) AS studbal
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT STUDENTID, SUM(AMOUNT) AS mysum FROM dbo.BillStudent
GROUP BY STUDENTID) AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT STUDENTID, SUM(AMOUNT) AS mysum
FROM dbo.FeePayment GROUP BY STUDENTID) AS b ON a.STUDENTID = b.STUDENTID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical banking system would keep a balance on the Account record (not the customer record, since a customer can have multiple accounts).  There would also be a Transaction table linked by foreign key to the account table.  Transactions would have a column indicating whether it's a debit or credit.  You could use triggers on the Transaction table to keep the Account record updated.

I work for a company that writes banking software :)